# How to Show Key Value Conditional Data in MatTable?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have data which is in form of key value. And also i want to put contion if key dont have the value or null then no need to show that key . I want to show this data in MatTable. I read the documentation for the MatTable but no where any solution here is my old code which i want to present in MatTable

```
<tbody *ngIf="product">
                      <tr>
                        <td>Category</td>
                        <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>SKU</td>
                        <td>{{product.sku}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr *ngIf="product.Fcc" >
                        <td>FCC</td>
                        <td>{{product.Fcc}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr *ngIf="product.condition" >
                        <td>Condition</td>
                        <td>{{product.condition}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr *ngIf="product.desc" >
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>{{product.desc }}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr *ngIf="detail.Frequency" >
                        <td>Frequency</td>
                        <td>{{detail.Frequency}} Mhz</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr *ngIf="product.weight" >
                        <td>Weight</td>
                        <td>{{detail.weight}} kg</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr *ngIf="product.region" >
                        <td>Region</td>
                        <td>{{product.region.toString()}}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
```